# windows 8 setup - "we can't tell if your PC is ready..."

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, upgrade

I've been trying to upgrade windows 7 to windows 8 for a while now, but it still gives me  errors.

I of course searched around for this question first, and here are some of the recommended things I've tried but haven't had work.

- completely uninstall and clear antivirus program (avast)
- tried the setup exe from both the one generated on my desktop, and the one I burned to a DVD
- tried booting into the windows DVD I burned (apparently I need to start with the setup before I boot into the DVD)
- started windows 7 in safe mode
- started windows 7 without anything else but Microsoft services (clean boot)
- uninstalled Catalyst Control Center
- unplugged all peripherals besides the keyboard and mouse
- cleaning temp folder

This is about everything that I could find on Microsoft's forums dealing with this issue, yet the problem persists.  I don't think the problem is a corrupt DVD as it does not work on the desktop either.

The two outcomes I've seen:

when I click the desktop icon to start the install - 
[image]

When I start the setup.exe on the DVD iso I burned - same result as above

When I start the setup in safe mode - the setup starts, and then randomly exits out and never continues

---

I've tried to upgrade a Win7 machine to 8 with no problem before.  I assume I am having problems this time because I am using a custom-built computer.  Specs (that matter)-

- Asrock Z87 Extreme4 Mobo
- Intel 4770k i7 Processor
- AMD Radeon HD 7790 GPU

---

It's especially unnerving that Microsoft doesn't supply any debug information besides "We don't know".

I've also run the Windows 8.1 Upgrade Assistant, and everything seems to be fine - 5 items "need review" or cannot be transferred, but that is not a problem.

Below are some resources I've already read through which haven't helped me.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/we-cant-tell-if-your-pc-is-ready-to-continue/117500cc-adc4-420b-bdae-01bd92ad14dc

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/update-from-windows-8-tutorial

---

I'd also like to mention that my current operating system is an evaluation copy of Windows 7 (i.e. the 90 day trial) if that is of any help.  Maybe this is preventing me from downloading needed updates to Win7?

Comment: To start: test your drives, test your RAM.

Comment: My HDD?  And my ram is fine.  I'll run a disk check but I'm not sure how that would affect this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly enough, Microsoft very confusingly markets their operating system.  Upon receiving online help, the gentleman on the line told me that my product key was upgrade only, and that Windows 8 Pro was needed if I didn't already own a copy of Windows (Which is weird... it wasn't well documented on their store page).

Wish the program would have simply said this before I messed with my settings and uninstalled my antivirus... Oh well...